# Illegal assignment from Object - Decimal

Tags: apex, process-builder

```
public class CountryrealignUpdate{
    @InvocableMethod
    public static void NewcountyUpdate(List<id> countyIds){

        Map<Id, New_Company__c> NewCompanyId = new Map<Id, New_Company__c>([select id,Alumni_Present__c,Alumni_contact_count__c from New_Company__c where id = :countyIds]);
        Map<Id, AggregateResult> AggregMap = new Map<Id, AggregateResult>([select id, count(Name) Name From Contact where Company_Realign__c = :countyIds GROUP BY id]);
        list<New_Company__c> newval = new list<New_Company__c>();

        for (Id NewCountyId : AggregMap.keySet())
        {
            newval.add(new New_Company__c(
                Id = NewCountyId, 
                Alumni_contact_count__c = AggregMap.get(NewCountyId).get('Name')
            ));
        }
        update newval;
    }
}
```

I am trying to assigning count of related contacts of Every New_Company__c's record.

`Alumni_contact_count__c` is a field in `New_Company__c` Object. `Contact` and `New_Company__c` is having lookup relationship.

I need to use process builder to update related New_Company__c's record whenever any changes happen in contact.

But from above code, I am getting `Illegal assignment from Object to Decimal`
 Error

Comment: I think you need to use Company_Realign__c  instead of "Id" in AggregMap  query. Because Id you currently use there is contact id. Also cast count as decimal while assigning to a field on New_Company__c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think your code has been written as per your requirement. Not sure why are you querying the New_Company__c records and also you should group by the records based on the parent lookup. Check the following code where I have used the type-casting so you should not get the above error.

```
public class CountryrealignUpdate{
@InvocableMethod
public static void NewcountyUpdate(List<id> countyIds){

    List<New_Company__c> newval = new List<New_Company__c>();

    for (AggregateResult ar : [select count(Id) totalCount, Company_Realign__c countyId From Contact where Company_Realign__c = :countyIds GROUP BY Company_Realign__c ] ){
        newval.add(new New_Company__c(
            Id = (Id) ar.get('countyId'), 
            Alumni_contact_count__c = (Decimal) ar.get('totalCount')
        ));
    }
    update newval;
}
```

Comment: Hi Sharma, Your post helped me but It is updating the New record only. It is not updating the old record.  Ex: Suppose I have New_Company__c record A and it is having 7 contacts And New_Company__c record B having 2 contacts. Now I am changing one contact from Record A to Record B (using lookup I am changing parent). Now the Record B is Having 4 contacts(Correct) But Record A is having 7 records(Wrong). Record A should also update. I mean Record A should show 6 records.

Comment: In that case, you will have to pass both parent record Ids in the countyIds parameter of the function. Not sure, if this is something possible using the process builder.

Comment: Process builder is not accepting two parameters from a single method. But I created another class and used in process builder Another action where i used a parameter in formula PRIORVALUE(Parameter). Now it is working. But do you have any idea on How many records can we update through process builder? Ex: if I update 50000 records will it work? I wondering about this

Answer (score 1):

When you `get` from a map, the compiler only knows that the type of the value is `Object` rather than a more specific data type such as `Decimal`. You have to add code to confirm the type conversion and keep the compiler happy.

In this case, I'm not sure of the pattern that will work given that the `count` is an integer value. The first one to try is this simple cast:

```
Alumni_contact_count__c = (Decimal) AggregMap.get(NewCountyId).get('Name')
```

but there are also methods such as `Decimal.valueOf` and `Integer.valueOf` that can be applied.

Comment: System.NullPointerException: Attempt to de-reference a null object Error is coming at "newval.add(new New_Company__c(
                Id = NewCountyId, 
                Alumni_contact_count__c = AggregMap.get(NewCountyId).get('Name')"

Comment: @Frank That is a different error related to your maps and map key logic.